# Diving a long String into small strings by delimiter

Tags: java, string, delimiter, divider

I'm kind of new to Java and I'm working on a little project. My problem is that I have a big String that contains lots of data delimited by `"$$$"`. I searched a little bit and I found the `chatAt()` method, but it's not what I'm looking for since I don't have a specified number of chars for each data.

I'm giving you an example for better understanding of my problem:

```
20160818120215$$$000$$$15.00$$$article3
```

I have a bigger output but I made a small example just to explain. Here I have the first data as a Date with this format: `2016/08/18,12h02m15s`. Then the second data is a code `000` that means something for me (don't mind it); then the third, which is a price `15.00 $`. The last one specifies which article is described.

I only need to dissect this string into smaller parts so that each time I receive it, I know that part 1 is for date, part 2 for the code, part 3 for the price and part 4 is the delimiter, which will always be `$$$`.

Comment: i got downvoted, i don't know why, my apologies if i broke some rule, got my answer thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Just use `yourString.split("\\$\\$\\$");`

Comment: Thank you mister !

Comment: I believe the pattern does not have to be that long :) See [my solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39015084/3832970). The backslashes are also looking rather nasty.

Answer (score 2):

String as a split method.
Do something like :

```
String myString = "20160818120215$$$000$$$15.00$$$article3";
String[] parts = myString.split("\\$\\$\\$"); // double backslah as split use a regex and $ is a reserved char in regex (thank Wiktor Stribiżew)
// parts[0] == 20160818120215
// parts[1] == 000
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to use [**`String#split`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method that accepts a regular expression. In regex, `$` matches the end of string, thus, you cannot use `$$$`.

You need to use `"\\${3}"` - that is, 3 `$` literal symbols. Or, you can get rid of the backslashes at all with `[$]{3}`:

```
String myString = "20160818120215$$$000$$$15.00$$$article3";
String[] parts = myString.split("[$]{3}");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
// => [20160818120215, 000, 15.00, article3]
```

See a [working Java demo](https://ideone.com/5io1ZE)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for all of your answer i started working with split, but then i discovered StringTokenizer which is amazing !

A few examples on how to use it :

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

In case someone comes by sometime, farwell :D